# UTF-8 is not the decoder

Tags: python-3.x, pipe, pcap

I'm using a program that reads data from a ubertooth-one device. I put the input data into a pipe file (made with mkfifo), but when i try to read the data i have the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/k1k4ss0/Escritorio/proyecto/tests/tmp.py", line 44, in interpretar
    print ("{}".format(fifo.readline()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

My code is this one:

```
# with FIFO as : '/tmp/pipe'
def interpretar():
  with open(FIFO) as fifo:
    while True:
      print ("{}".format(fifo.readline()))
```

The command excecuted is `ubertooth-rx -q /tmp/pipe`
following the documentation:

`• -q <file.pcap> : Capture packets to PCAP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are getting is not unicode/text so can't be decoded as such.  Try `open(FIFO, "rb")` to open in binary mode and `read` (instead of `readline`) to read binary data.

Comment: yeah it should be bytes or raw data.. i will try what you say